# dest.on is not a function in gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to make gulp tasks but after initializing gulp and work in coding I got this error below, in sass and pug tasks
what I understand the problem is on `pipe()` and  I checked the Docs I can't see something wrong in my code

gulpfile.js
[image]

the error

[image]

Comment: Your issue _might_ come from `.pipe(connect.reload)`: the [documented](https://github.com/avevlad/gulp-connect) way is `.pipe(connect.reload())`. (Notice the difference between passing the function `connect.reload` and passing its result.)

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in `connect.reload` should be `connect.reload()`